# How to use keybinds with init.vim file in VSCode-Neovim

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, vscode-extensions, neovim

I am setting Extension `VSCode Neovim` for `Mac`.

I added the following code to `settings.json` to use `init.vim` with my keybinds set.

I can use vim in `vscode`, but key bindings don't work.

Do I need other settings besides `settings.json`?

---

`settings.json`

```
"vscode-neovim.neovimExecutablePaths.darwin": "/usr/local/bin/nvim",
"vscode-neovim.neovimInitVimPaths.darwin": "/Users/myname/.config/nvim/init.vim"
```

`init.vim`

```
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set expandtab
set textwidth=0
set autoindent
set hlsearch
set clipboard=unnamed
syntax on

noremap <C-a> ^
noremap <C-e> $
inoremap <silent> jj <ESC>
noremap <C-j> <esc>
noremap! <C-j> <esc>
```

---

VSCode Version: 1.62.3

VSCode Neovim: 0.0.82

NVIM v0.5.1

Mac BigSur 11.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VSCode-Neovim works differently than regular Neovim, specifically in **insert mode** is managed by VS Code using **[keybindings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization)**

For example if you need to map `jj` to `<Esc>` you can add this to your keybindings.json

```
{
    "command": "vscode-neovim.compositeEscape1",
    "key": "j",
    "when": "neovim.mode == insert && editorTextFocus",
    "args": "j"
}
```

Most of Ctrl keys are already mapped by the [extensions](https://github.com/asvetliakov/vscode-neovim#insert-mode-special-keys).